# javascript で get と 関数定義の違いが分からない

Tags: javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get

```
var obj = {
  get hoge() {
  }
}
```

とするのと、

```
var obj = {
  hoge: function hoge() {
  }
}
```

とするのとでは、なにが違うのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

定義したプロパティの使い方が異なります。

`get`で定義したプロパティは、参照すると`get`関数が自動的に呼び出されます。関数の返り値が参照結果として得られます。

```
var obj = {
  get hoge() {
    return "abc";
  }
}

console.log(obj.hoge) // "abc"
```

上の例のように、`obj.hoge`の値を得ようとすると`get`で定義した関数が自動的に呼び出されます。

---

一方、関数定義の場合は`obj.hoge`は関数が入っている普通のプロパティとなりますから、呼び出すには明示的に関数呼び出しをする必要があります。

```
var obj = {
  hoge: function hoge() {
    return "abc";
  }
}
console.log(obj.hoge()); // "abc"
```